# Why weren't the newest version of dependencies fetched?

Tags: rust, github-actions, rust-cargo

I have added dependencies in a Rust project like this:

```toml
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git" }
```

When I built this project in GitHub Actions, I found it got the legacy version of `rust_wheel`:

```
   Compiling rust_wheel v0.1.0 (https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git#5dffd2f5)
error[E0412]: cannot find type `Json` in module `content`
  --> /usr/local/cargo/git/checkouts/rust_wheel-8476ff1b418e67f8/5dffd2f/src/common/util/model_convert.rs:35:50
   |
35 | pub fn box_rest_response<T>(data: T) -> content::Json<String> where T: Serialize + Default {
   |                                                  ^^^^ not found in `content`
   |
help: consider importing one of these items
   |
1  | use diesel::pg::types::sql_types::Json;
```

GitHub Actions got the version `5dffd2f5`, but the newest version of `rust_wheel` was `52bccd9a4a3ece5cf9416510b7f8a4274d205da1`. Why didn't it get the newest one? What should I do to make it get the newest versions of dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you have a `Cargo.lock` file, which is designed to prevent updating dependencies from under your nose by keeping track of the specific versions you're using. If there are changes in the git repository that you want to use, you can update the `Cargo.lock` file using [`cargo update`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-update.html):

```
cargo update -p rust_wheel
```

Another option is to explicitly define the revision to use in your `Cargo.toml`:

```toml
rust_wheel = { git = "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/rust_wheel.git", rev = "52bccd9a" }
```